# Autofac: Performance of Injecting whole AggregateService Instead of Concrete Service

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

Supposing I have a controller that is accepting AggregatedService DI registered in container in Autofac:

```
public interface IMyAggregateService
{
  IFirstService FirstService { get; }
  ISecondService SecondService { get; }
  IThirdService ThirdService { get; }
  IFourthService FourthService { get; }
}

public class SomeController
{
  private readonly IMyAggregateService _aggregateService;

  public SomeController(IMyAggregateService aggregateService)
  {
    _aggregateService = aggregateService;
  }
}
```

After some time i have created another controler: `SomeAnotherController` which requires one of the services that was registered in `AggregateService` (`IFirstService` as an example).

What would be better solution:

1. Inject `IMyAggregateService` to `SomeAnotherController` and use instance of FirstService

or

2. Register FirstService as a separate Type in autofac and inject just this service to `SomeAnotherController`

Regarding solution 1) I know that there is a dynamic proxy created for agregated services but is the type actually resolved when we invode a method on a property of AgregatedService or it is done when injecting IAgregateService to constuctor?

1 or 2 would be better solution in terms of performance?

Comment: Firstly, you will already have registered `FirstService`. Secondly, if your `SomeAnotherController` object doesn't need anything in the aggregate service, then don't inject that. Performance shouldn't even be a thought here.

Comment: @DavidG thanks, SomeOtherController needs IFirstService which is inside IMyAggregateService but as I understand from your response i do not need to inject IMyAggregateService just to use IFirstService I need just to inject simply IFirstService and this service is already registred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a *strictly performance perspective* it's going to depend on several things, like:

- What's the lifetime scope of the aggregate service (singleton, per-request, etc.)?
- What's the lifetime scope of the individual services?
- How "expensive" is it to create the individual services?

...and so on. There's not a concrete answer. For example, if *everything* was registered as singletons, the perf will be the same either way - all the singletons will be created, cached, and looked up from the cache. On the other hand, if the aggregate service is instance-per-dependency, it will re-create the instance every time you ask for one, which is inherently more expensive than using a cached instance.

However, from a *patterns perspective* you should only inject *what you need* in the controller. By injecting the whole aggregate service in the second controller, you're effectively saying, from an API perspective, that you *must have all four things* in the aggregate service even though you only use the first one. That leaves you with a somewhat confusing API, especially when it comes to refactoring and unit tests. It's almost like service location, just with "several strongly-typed entries in the list of services to locate."

**Your best bet is to just inject what you need into the second controller.** The strong likelihood is that it'll be better perf anyway, but more importantly you'll have a better API that will be easier to use and refactor in the long term. It's win-win.